# Do you have to have seen a tree in person to use it as a destination for the Transport via Plants spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*transport via plants*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/transport-via-plants) spell description says, in part:

> You must have seen or touched the destination plant at least once before.

If you used *scrying* on someone and saw a plant that could be used for the *transport via plants* spell, can you then use that plant as a destination for *transport via plants*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## You only need to have seen the plant

The description for *[Scrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying)* reads

> You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you [...] the spell creates an invisible sensor within 10 feet of the target. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there

There is no difference built into this or other features that allow different sight between in-person seeing and the sight granted by the spell/effect

*[Transport via Plants](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/transport-via-plants)* reads:

> You must have seen or touched the destination plant at least once before.

Again there is no distinction drawn between in-person seeing and seeing by another means.

The *Scrying* spell allows you to see the plant and that is all that is required for *Transport via Plants* to work. This is a good example of how powerful *Scrying* can be and how spells can be used creatively.